# picture's backgroundcolor in picturebox

Tags: vb.net

how can i change the background color of a picture saving from a picturebox in vb.net.In my form there is a drawing section.after drawing i am saving the picture as jpeg.but the image's background color is black.so i can't see anything that i have drawn.the drawing pen color is also black.if anyone knows please help me.thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the easiest way is to paint the background when the image object is created (sample initializing the background to being white):

```
Dim theImage As Image = New Bitmap(someWidth, someHeight)
Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(theImage)
    g.Clear(Color.White)
End Using
```

Comment: thank you very much.its also working good.when i click the clear button the image will gone.but after i trying to draw a new one i can't draw.because i initialize the picture as picturebox1.image=new bitmap....etc in the form load.where can i place this code?thank you

Comment: I would move the initialization of the image to a separate method that you call from Form_Load, and also from the click event of the Clear button.

Comment: i added the initialization of the image in the form_load and the click event of the clear button.but when i click the clear button the image will cleared and at the mouse move on the picturebox the last drawned image will shawn .if you can please help me,and how can i validate the picturebox is empty means i doesn't want to permit to save a empty image.thank you

Answer (score 0):

To use this the following code:

```
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Bmp Files(*.bmp)|*.bmp|Gif Files(*.gif)|*.gif|Jpg Files(*.jpg)|*.jpg"
 OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
 Textbox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
 PicText.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
```